# Leaflet add tooltips to Easy Buttons

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

I have a very simple leaflet map which has a set of easy buttons whose function is to add and remove layers from the map.

I'd like to set tooltip or mouseover or hover so when the user moves the mouse over the buttons they get a message. Simple.

Here's an example of the code for the layers, then for the buttons:

```
//layer coding

var buildings = L.geoJson(buildings,{
 style: function(feature, layer){
    return { 
        color: "purple",
        fillOpacity: 9,
        weight: 2
    };
},

}).addTo(map);


//button coding

L.easyButton('<img class="icon" src="icons/house.png">',

function(btn, map){

if (map.hasLayer(buildings)){
    map.removeLayer(buildings);
} else {
    map.addLayer(buildings);
};

}).addTo( map );
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the last line works for me.

```
//layer coding

var buildings = L.geoJson(buildings,{
 style: function(feature, layer){
    return { 
        color: "purple",
        fillOpacity: 9,
        weight: 2
    };
},

}).addTo(map);


//button coding

L.easyButton('<img class="icon" src="icons/house.png">',

function(btn, map){

if (map.hasLayer(buildings)){
    map.removeLayer(buildings);
} else {
    map.addLayer(buildings);
};

},'Interact with the map').addTo(map);
```

Comment: Totally works! Thanks! ?how????

Comment: Here is the relevant Github issue comment: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/issues/39#issuecomment-196478636